# Как правильно оформить условие? Входят ли в строку искомые элементы?

Tags: php

Есть много мерный массив.

```
$arr = [ ['id' => 1, 'data' => ['sort' => 3], 'type' => 101, 'val' => '1600000001.60085'], 
['id' => 2, 'data' => ['sort' => 4], 'type' => 321, 'val' => '1000060000.95275'], 
['id' => 3, 'data' => ['sort' => 1], 'type' => 210, 'val' => '2050000047.31715'],
['id' => 4, 'data' => ['sort' => 5], 'type' => 764, 'val' => '3200000000.46325'], 
['id' => 5, 'data' => ['sort' => 2], 'type' => 357, 'val' => '2146763220.81125'] ];
```

Нужно добавить в каждый элемент массива обозначение группы(group = '*') согласно следующему условию:

- если поле 'type' начинается  на 3[0-1,3-5,7-9], то группа c
- во всех остальных случаях группа d.

Как это сделать правильно и красиво не используя кучу условий?

Comment: `если на 3[0-1,3-5,7-9], то группа c` - если на 3 что? по какому полю-то

Comment: @Manitikyl, и так постоянно :(

Comment: @Let'ssayPie даже вопрос нормально задать не могут, совсем обленились

Comment: @Manitikyl, ну мы же телепатыыы ыы)))

Comment: Поправил) поле 'type'

Comment: Что-то не понятно, что значит эта скобка? [0-1,3-5,7-9]

Comment: диапазон от 0 -1 , от 3 до 5. т.е. 2, 6 не попадают под условие

Comment: @ZIBERMINSK, а начинаться должно с 3 всегда?

Comment: Верно! Начинается с 3. А вторая цифра это диапазон значений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой вариант:

```
$arr = array_map(function ($row) {
    $row['group'] = (preg_match('~^3[0-1|3-5|7-9]{1}\d+$~', $row['type'])) ? 'c' : 'd';
    return $row;
}, $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: array_map - проходиться по всему массиву и в качестве callback возвращает отредактированный массив. preg_match - ищет соответствие по заданной маске?

Comment: @ZIBERMINSK, сами себе объяснили?) `preg_match` в данном случае ищет соответствие в type по заданной маске, вы правы

Comment: @ZIBERMINSK, поправил регулярку, теперь точно все ищет.

Comment: @ZIBERMINSK, один вопрос, вам диапазон нужен только для второй цифры? или для всех последующих после 3?

Comment: Для одной после 3

Comment: @ZIBERMINSK, минутку, тогда сейчас исправляю :)

Comment: {1} - второй символ. А как тогда все после 3?

Comment: @ZIBERMINSK, идут обычные цифры далее

Comment: {1} - это не второй символ. это длина второго символа.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81068/discussion-between-lets-say-pie-and-ziber-minsk).